# Best Data Structure/Algorithm for insert/delete/rank/select queries

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

So far, I know that self-balancing BST like AVL tree and Red Black Tree can do these operations in O(log n) times.

However, to use these structures, we must implement AVL tree or RB tree ourselves.

I have heard that there is an algorithm/ implementation of these four operations without using self-balancing BST.

With our own defined structure, we need to write so many lines. However, I have heard that there is a possibility of supporting these four operators in less than 100 lines code :\

Do you guys have any ideas on how this should be done?

Other than BST, is there any other possible options?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/rbtree.html ?

Comment: What if I don't want to use any BST at all? Is there an alternative way? :)

Comment: You can use a skip list, which is easy to implement but not so easy to augment for rank/select. A treap with rank/select could also be implemented in under 60 lines of code

Comment: Oh and if you insert/delete integers in a small range (say [0, 100000]) or if you can preprocess the queries offline to compress them, you can use a binary-indexed tree. Rank is O (log n) and select is O (log^2 n) with this approach

Comment: Thank you all. I have tried using binary-indexed tree by doing precomputation on all the queries first. So that we do not have to deal with 10^9 max value (because the total numbers are only 50,000)
The code for the binary-indexed tree is very short and it's fast. But, how do you analyze the complexity for select algorithm?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to maintain a set of integers and you can do a coordinate compression as a preprocessing step (e.g. because your algorithm is offline and knows all the future queries), you can use a [binary-indexed tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) to support insert/delete/rank/select of numbers in O(log n) per operation. Here's an example in C++:

```c++
int tree[N];  // where N is the number of compressed coordinates
const int maxl = floor(log(N)/log(2));

void insert(int i) { // 1 <= i <= N
  for (; i <= N; i += i & -i) ++tree[i];
}

void remove(int i) { // 1 <= i <= N
  for (; i <= N; i += i & -i) --tree[i];
}

int rank(int i) { // 1 <= i <= N
  int sum = 0;
  for (; i; i -= i & -i) sum += tree[i];
  return sum;
}

int select(int k) { // k is 1-based
  int ans = 0, s = 0;
  for (int i = maxl; i >= 0; --i) // maxl = largest i s.t. (1<<i) <= N
    if (s + tree[ans + (1<<i)] < k) {
      ans += 1<<i;
      s += tree[ans];
    }
  return ans+1;
}
```

The `select` function is somewhat magical. It reuses the results from higher bits to compute the prefix sum of `ans + (1<<i)` in O(1), which is pretty cool IMHO :) This way it only takes time O(log n), instead of the O(log^2 n) that is easy to achieve using a standard binary search.

Comment: I think that the "insert" and "delete" operations being described here aren't the same as what you're doing. I believe the OP is talking about "insert an element into a set" versus "insert another marble into slot x."

Comment: @templatetypedef Please explain what the difference is :) Assume that you have precomputed a bijective function from your universe to the set of integers [1..N], for example via sorting. This is an offline algorithm, after all

Comment: I was assuming the goal was to store an ordered set of element S supporting the operations insert, delete, along with "what is the kth smallest element?" and "what is the index of element x in the set S?" Then again, it's possible that insert, delete, rank, and select mean something totally different here.

Comment: @templatetypedef That's exactly what my example code does. However you need to map your universe S to integers in the range [1..N].

Comment: So that would mean that the operations run in time proportional to the log of the universe size versus the log of the number of elements, and it won't work for objects like strings that can't be bijected to the integers?

Comment: @templatetypedef It's offline. If you have strings, you sort them and you automatically have a bijection string -> rank that preserves the ordering

Comment: Good answer. Note that `select` should guard against accessing indices out of bounds by adding `ans + (1<<i) <= N` in the condition.