# Number of elements less than X

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I need a structure that can quickly (log N) count the number of elements smaller than a certain value/modify values. I know it is easy to do with an R-B tree or similar, but I wanted to save time by using STL, which already implements these trees. However, I can't find any function that would do what I need - is it even possible, possibly using a trick of some sort? I know it requires storing the number of elements in every subtree, which it might not do normally.

Comment: There's [Boost Intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/intrusive.html), but as far as I know, there's no good way with the STL.

Comment: Do you need fast insertions and deletions too?

Comment: If you restrict yourself to G++, it has an [order-statistic tree implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230734/c-stl-order-statistic-tree). That is of course if you need online insertion and deletion, otherwise you can use a sorted array. If you have a compact universe or you can compress it using preprocessing, you can also use a [binary-indexed tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780668/best-data-structure-algorithm-for-insert-delete-rank-select-queries/23233101#23233101)

Comment: Yes, I need insertions/deletions too. Guess I'll just stick with writing R-B code myself since I can't use non-standard libraries.

Comment: Treaps are much faster and easier to code, by the way

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a simple sorted vector or array:

```
std::vector<int> V;
// (fill V with values)
std::sort(V.begin(), V.end());

int numValsLessThan5 = std::lower_bound(V.begin(), V.end(), 5) - V.begin();
int numValsLessThanOrEqualTo5 = std::upper_bound(V.begin(), V.end(), 5) - V.begin();
```

`upper/lower_bound` has logarithmic complexity when used on containers which support random access.

Comment: You can't modify it in (log N) though, guess I should've mentioned that.